# Why can't I get the location by the NETWORK_PROVIDER as follows?

Tags: android, android-location

It is very simple.

But I see nothing appears on the logcat.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_selection);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                if (location != null) {
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

                    Log.d("MapSelectionActivity", longitude + " " + latitude);
                } else {
                    Log.d("MapSelectionActivity", "location unavailable");
                }
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };

        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }
```

I am sure my phone is connected to a wifi access point, which enables the phone to access the internet.

Comment: Check whether your phone's location sharing setting are proper.

Comment: @MohitVerma  what do you mean pls?

Comment: if you don't select google location service or gps satellite in Location service, you will not get new location or may get old location.

Answer (score 0):

First change the line below:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

To:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);
```

Like it's said [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29):

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
```

...
*minTime    minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds*
...

**EDIT**
I found this tutorial [here](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/), which has a simpler usage:

```
LocationListener&nbsp;locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, this.locationListener);


private final class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location locFromGps) {
          // called when the listener is notified with a location update from the GPS
      }
      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
         // called when the GPS provider is turned off (user turning off the GPS on the phone)
      }
      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
         // called when the GPS provider is turned on (user turning on the GPS on the phone)
      }
      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
         // called when the status of the GPS provider changes
      }
}
```

Comment: Please confirm, that your activity `implements LocationListener, LocationSource`. Thanks

Comment: Check the EDIT I made and see if it fixes it for you. The tutorial is much simpler.

Comment: I seems that you accepted an answer so I guess it was something related to the permissions ... or something else, hope it is working for you.