# Updating Activity with Latitude/Longitude values returned from a Service

Tags: android, service, gps, android-activity, locationlistener

I'm trying to write a simple app that updates the MainActivity with the Lat/Lng values returned by the service. But it always returns the null value.  I have added permissions and added TheService.java as service in AndroidManifest.xml file...Kindly tell me where I have gone wrong.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv1, tv2;
IntentFilter filter;
receive rec;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    filter = new IntentFilter("Updated");
    rec = new receive();
    Intent gps_int = new Intent(this,TheService.class);
    startService(gps_int);      

}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(rec);
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    rec = new receive();
    registerReceiver(rec, filter);      
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public class receive extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv1.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("lat"));
        tv2.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("lon"));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast Executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BR Latitude "+intent.getExtras().getString("lat"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}}
```

### TheService.java

```
public class TheService extends Service implements LocationListener {
LocationManager lm;
Location loc;
double lat = 0;
double lon = 0;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
    loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    onLocationChanged(loc);
     return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onCreate()
{


}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    updateui(location);
}

private void updateui(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lon = location.getLongitude();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Intent gps_intent = new Intent("Updated");
    gps_intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
    gps_intent.putExtra("lon", lon);
    sendBroadcast(gps_intent);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

Comment: Check my answer here whether it helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669546/why-cant-i-get-the-location-by-the-network-provider-as-follows/17669695#17669695

Comment: What I see is you are starting the service and immediately returning the last known location. I am not sure but looks like your service is trying to send a broadcast even before the `onResume` in your activity gets called, so basically looks like your receiver is not registered when the broadcast is made. Not sure though. Try adding logs to see what happens first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use the [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) for the location, that's easier to handle.
2. What for do you even need a Service? Having a location listener in your Activity is totally fine.
3. If you want to stay with the Service, than [bind](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) the Activity to it, instead of using a Broadcast.

Comment: 4. You can use a `Handler`-`Messenger` to send data back to the `Activity` from your `Serivce`.

Comment: I get updates from Service to activity, but not the location updates in the service. Please provide me a sample code to get location updates via service.

Comment: See the link above to the Google Play Services or check the Android training here https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html You will get all the information you need from there.